# How to retrieve document elements - Document ready

Tags: javascript

Could somebody please explain why this button does not work? The error in my console indicates that `var button = document.getElementById('next');` is returning `null`.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script>
        ...
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="next">Say hi</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var button = document.getElementById('next');
function sayHi(){
    alert('Hi there');
}

button.addEventListener('click',sayHi,false);
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*At the time the script runs* you have no element with the id `next`.

- Move the `<script>` element so it appears *after* the element with that id *or*
- Wrap the content of the script in a function, and bind that function as an event handler for an event that will run after the element exists

e.g.

```
function sayHi(){
    alert('Hi there');
}

function setUpButton() {
    var button = document.getElementById('next');
    button.addEventListener('click',sayHi,false);
}

addEventListener('load', setUpButton);
```

Answer (score 4):

Run the JS **after** the HTML has loaded. When you call the JS in the head, the button doesn't exist yet, it's rendered after the JS is called.

This will work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <button id="next">Say hi</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        ...
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script runs too early and your DOM (Document Object Model) is **not yet ready**.
 If your `<script>` is located inside the **`<head>` of your document**  use the  `onreadystatechange` (modern browsers):

### DOM ready - inside `<head>`

```
<script>
document.onreadystatechange = function () { 
    if(document.readyState === "interactive") { // use "complete" as a 'load' alternative
         /* (DOM is now read and ready to be manipulated) your code here */
    }
}​
</script>
</head>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/readystatechange
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/api/document/readystate

---

### DOM ready - before the closing `</body>`

If you need to support IE8< put all your JS before the closing `</body>` tag:

```
<!-- Your page elements before the script tag -->

<script>
   /* (DOM is now read and ready to be manipulated) your code here */
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: The readystatechange event is likely to fire multiple times. It probably shouldn't be used for this without testing that document.readyState == "complete".

Answer (score 0):

You have positioned the script to run before the document is fully rendered, so it wont be able to find the button. 
Run the script at the end of the document i.e

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<button id="next">Say hi</button>
<script>
    ...
</script>
</body>
```